# RecycleView scrolling issue when change language

Tags: java, android, kotlin, graphics

Language: kotlin
Android studio
gradle 6.3

recycleView was working fine but when i change the language to arabic it will not let me click or scroll anything

here is a video to make the issue clearer https://streamable.com/dv6ap2